# Coherence Cache Eviction Policy

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

I have following cache configuration file,
I want to add evcition policy for each cache-mapping, lets say

Data older than 5 minutes in `MY_SEND_SMS_SIZE_CACHE`

Data older than 10days in `MY_REG_AUTH_CACHE`

will be removed automatically.

How I can configure this file?

**coherence-cache-config_imos.xml**

```
<cache-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config
                     coherence-cache-config.xsd">

        <caching-scheme-mapping>
                <cache-mapping>
                        <cache-name>MY_SEND_SMS_SIZE_CACHE</cache-name>
                        <scheme-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</scheme-name>
                </cache-mapping>

                <cache-mapping>
                        <cache-name>MY_REG_AUTH_CACHE</cache-name>
                        <scheme-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</scheme-name>
                </cache-mapping>


        </caching-scheme-mapping>

        <caching-schemes>

                <distributed-scheme>
                        <scheme-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</scheme-name>
                        <service-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</service-name>

                        <serializer>
                                <instance>
                                        <class-name>com.tangosol.io.pof.SafeConfigurablePofContext
                                        </class-name>
                                        <init-params>
                                                <init-param>
                                                        <param-type>String</param-type>
                                                        <param-value>
                                                                <!-- pof-config.xml path should be set -->
                                                                pof-config.xml
                                                        </param-value>
                                                </init-param>
                                        </init-params>
                                </instance>
                        </serializer>
                        <backing-map-scheme>
                                <local-scheme />
                        </backing-map-scheme>
                        <autostart>true</autostart>
                </distributed-scheme>
        </caching-schemes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have editted conf file as following then everything works fine, I mean data older than 10 seconds are evicted

```
    <caching-scheme-mapping>
            <cache-mapping>
                    <cache-name>MY_SEND_SMS_SIZE_CACHE</cache-name>
                    <scheme-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</scheme-name>
            </cache-mapping>

            <cache-mapping>
                    <cache-name>MY_REG_AUTH_CACHE</cache-name>
                    <scheme-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</scheme-name>
            </cache-mapping>


    </caching-scheme-mapping>

    <caching-schemes>

            <distributed-scheme>
                    <scheme-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</scheme-name>
                    <service-name>MY_UserDistributedCache</service-name>

                    <serializer>
                            <instance>
                                    <class-name>com.tangosol.io.pof.SafeConfigurablePofContext
                                    </class-name>
                                    <init-params>
                                            <init-param>
                                                    <param-type>String</param-type>
                                                    <param-value>
                                                            <!-- pof-config.xml path should be set -->
                                                            pof-config.xml
                                                    </param-value>
                                            </init-param>
                                    </init-params>
                            </instance>
                    </serializer>
                   <backing-map-scheme>
                    <local-scheme>
                      <scheme-name>MY_REG_AUTH_CACHE</scheme-name>
                      <expiry-delay>10s</expiry-delay>
                    </local-scheme>
                </backing-map-scheme>
                    <autostart>true</autostart>
            </distributed-scheme>
    </caching-schemes>
```